# There is an implant in me, is there a way to identify the frequency it is receiving signals on?

Tags: radio-interception, gnu-radio

There is an implant in me, is there a way to identify the frequency it is receiving signals on?

I don't want to share the evidence and my reasoning for believing there is an implant in me, you can either take my word for it or not.

I want to find the frequency it is receiving signals on, so far I have used dvb-t dongle to use it as an SDR, and I have manually scanned the entire frequency range provided by it, which is 24MHz to 1700MHz, which was very tiring, but I couldn't identify anything suspicious, it could be possible that as I was tuning, the frequency it was receiving signals on was not the tuned one.

I want to know if there a way to identify the frequency of the signal? How? And what equipment would I need?

Comment: Crosspost: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/74850 Some pretty decent answers there.

Comment: @multithr3at3d One of the user there asked me to consider posting here, so I posted here.